# Green's identities for bilaplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Derive the Green's identities in local and integral form for the bilaplacian. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you please provide some background and motivation for you question? What have you done so far, where did you stuck, and what are the definitions of your main objects?

Comment: It looks like a homework question, Green's identities are indeed useful for solving some problems like Dirichlet problem etc. for getting these identities we usually apply Green or divergence (Gauss–Ostrogradsky) theorems.

Answer (score 3):

**Notation:**

- $\Delta$ - Laplacian operator,
- $\mbox{div}$ is a divergence (of a vector),
- $\nabla$ is a gradient,  $\vartheta$ is a unit (outward)
  normal vector defined positive away from the region $D$,
- $\partial
     D$ is a boudary of $D$.

Let $u$ and $v$ be scalar functions. 
We use Green's identities for the Laplacian ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities)). Let us denote $\Delta u = U$, and $\Delta v=V$.
Since $\Delta^2$ is a (formal) self-adjoint operator (it should be verified) we have that $L=L^*$ thus
$$uLv-vL^*u=uLv-vLu=u \Delta^2 v - v \Delta^2 u= u \Delta V - v \Delta U=$$
$$=\underbrace{(u \Delta V - V \Delta u)}_{{\tiny{\mbox{Green's identity for } \Delta}}} + \underbrace{(U \Delta v - v \Delta U)}_{{\tiny{\mbox{Green's identity for } \Delta}}}+V\Delta u-U\Delta v=$$
$$=\mbox{div} (u \nabla V - V \nabla u)+\mbox{div} (U \nabla v - v \nabla U)+V\Delta u-U\Delta v$$
Since $\mbox{div}$ is a linear operator, $\mbox{div}{(\phi F)}= \nabla(\phi) \cdot F +\phi\mbox{div}(F)$, where $\phi$ a scalar valued function and $F$ is a vector field and $\Delta f= \nabla \cdot \nabla f$
we obtain
$$\mbox{div} (u \nabla V) - \mbox{div} (V \nabla u)+\mbox{div} (U \nabla v) - \mbox{div}(v \nabla U)+V\Delta u-U\Delta v=  $$
$$=\mbox{div} (u \nabla V)- \mbox{div}(v \nabla U)-\nabla V \cdot \nabla u - V\mbox{div}(\nabla u) + \nabla U \cdot \nabla v + U\mbox{div}(\nabla v)+V\Delta u-U\Delta v=$$
$$\mbox{div} (u \nabla V)- \mbox{div}(v \nabla U)-\nabla V \cdot \nabla u - V\nabla \cdot(\nabla u) + \nabla U \cdot \nabla v + U\nabla \cdot(\nabla v)+V\Delta u-U\Delta v =$$
$$\mbox{div} (u \nabla V)- \mbox{div}(v \nabla U)-\nabla V \cdot \nabla u - V\Delta u + \nabla U \cdot \nabla v + U \Delta v+V\Delta u-U\Delta v =$$
$$\mbox{div} (u \nabla V)- \mbox{div}(v \nabla U)-\nabla V \cdot \nabla u + \nabla U \cdot \nabla v  =$$
$$\mbox{div} (u \nabla V)-\nabla u \cdot \nabla V- \mbox{div}(U \nabla v) + \nabla U \cdot \nabla v  =$$
$$=\left[\mbox{div}(u \nabla V)-\nabla u\cdot \nabla V\right] -\left[\mbox{div}(v \nabla U)-\nabla v\cdot \nabla U\right]= $$
$$=\mbox{div}\left[u\nabla(\Delta v)-v\nabla(\Delta^2 u) \right]+\left[\nabla v \cdot \nabla(\Delta^2 u)- \nabla u \cdot \nabla(\Delta^2 v)\right]$$
Rewriting the 2nd bracket we get 
$$\nabla v \cdot \nabla(\Delta^2 u)=\mbox{div}\left[(\nabla v)(\Delta U)\right]-(\Delta v)(\Delta u)$$
$$\nabla u \cdot \nabla(\Delta^2 v)=\mbox{div}\left[(\nabla u)(\Delta v)\right]-(\Delta u)(\Delta v)$$
Hence,
$$u \Delta^2 v - v \Delta^2 u=\mbox{div}\left[u\nabla(\Delta^2 v)- v\nabla(\Delta^2 u)+\nabla v(\Delta u)- \nabla u(\Delta v)\right]=\mbox{div}\vec{Q}$$
Finally, by integrating it over the volume $D$ and applying Gauss–Ostrogradsky theorem we obtain
$$\int_D \left(u \Delta^2 v - v \Delta^2 u\right) dx=\int_D \mbox{div}\vec{Q}dx=\int_{\partial D}\vartheta\cdot \vec{Q}dS= $$
$$=\int_{\partial D}\left(u \frac{\partial (\Delta v)}{\partial \vartheta}-v\frac{\partial (\Delta u)}{\partial \vartheta}+\Delta u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vartheta}-\Delta v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vartheta}  \right)dS.$$